# Returning mock objects from factory girl

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking, factory-bot, ruby-mocha

I am using Mocha and Factory_girl in a JRuby rails application.  When I call the factory I would like to return the objects with some mocking already done.  Here is a code snippet of what I am trying to do.

```
Factory.define :tweet_feed_with_tweets, :parent => :tweet_feed do |t|
  t.expects(:pull_tweets).returns([Factory.build(:status),Factory.build(:status)])
end
```

Because I do not want my unit and functional test to actually pull from the twitter API i want to stub the method so it returns what I want.  But, this is not working.  The object comes back without any stubbing done.  Is there a way to actually have stubbing performed on an object created with factory girl before it gets returned to you?

Comment: Have you worked out the answer yet? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation & source code for `factory_girl`, it looks like the object yielded to the block (`t`, in your example) is an instance of a `Factory` and not an instance of the object you want to construct (the `tweet_feed_with_tweets`, in your example). This means that setting an expectation for the `pull_tweets` method on `t` is setting the expectation on the `Factory` instance and not on the object that will be constructed when you call `Factory(:tweet_feed_with_tweets)`. I think this explains why your example is not working as you expect.

I may be wrong, but I can't see a way of adding the expectation within the `Factory.define` block. You've probably already thought of this, but I think you'd be better off adding the expectation in the test after you've constructed the instance :-

```
def test_should_do_something
  tweet_feed = Factory(:tweet_feed)
  tweet_feed.expects(:pull_tweets).returns([Factory.build(:status), Factory.build(:status)])
  # test stuff here
end
```

If you need this in multiple places, you can extract it into a method :-

```
def test_should_do_something
  tweet_feed = build_tweet_feed_with_tweets
  # test stuff here
end

private

def build_tweet_feed_with_tweets
  tweet_feed = Factory(:tweet_feed)
  tweet_feed.expects(:pull_tweets).returns([Factory.build(:status), Factory.build(:status)])
  return tweet_feed
end
```

A couple of other thoughts :-

1. I think setting expectations in such a hidden away place is probably a bad idea anyway.
2. If you are going to do it, I would have thought using `stubs` was more appropriate than `expects`.
3. It might be worth separating the `pull_tweets` method (and any similar methods) into a `TwitterAPI` class. That way it wouldn't seem so bad that you need to set up an expectation on the `TwitterAPI` in the test.

I hope some of that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Callbacks are now available:

```
Factory.define :tweet_feed_with_tweets, :parent => :tweet_feed do |t|
  t.after_build do |tt|  
    tt.expects(:pull_tweets).returns([Factory.build(:status),Factory.build(:status)])
  end
end
```